# using x:Bind with MvvmCross

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, mvvmcross, uwp

while trying to code the TipCalc example in MvvmCross, i try to use x:Bind instead of the regular Binding (In universal application programming)

my code behind looks like this:

```
public sealed partial class TipView 
{
    public new TipViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (TipViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }

    public TipView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and my xaml looks like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" 
          Margin="12,0,12,0"
          Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
          >
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock
                Text="SubTotal"
                />
            <TextBox 
                Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SubTotal, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                />
.
.
.
```

when compiling this i get the following error:

```
Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(350,5): Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyPropertyInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'.
```

i'm using the MvvmCross libs of 3.5.1 version (last stable)

is it a bug ? or something i am missing here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use following syntax in my code

```
public TipViewModel Vm => (TipViewModel) ViewModel;
```

And the binding would be

```
Text="{x:Bind Vm.SubTotal, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Not sure why you would get your error, your view does inherit from `MvxWindowsPage`?

Comment: i do inherit from MvxWindowsPage
ViewModel is property of MvxWindowsPage.

by create a new Vm it seems like the values are not changing when changing the slider
it looks like another instance of dataContext...

Comment: Any reason why you are mewing there viewmodel?

Comment: according their tutorial in:
[https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Tip-Calc-A-Universal-Windows-App-UI-Project]

`public new TipViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return (TipViewModel) base.ViewModel; }
    set { base.ViewModel = value; }
}`

Comment: You know what, I recently had to figure out how to do a specific thing with a uwp app and blogged it here http://depblog.weblogs.us/2015/11/23/mvvmcross-uwp-splitview/ take a look how it is set up

Comment: i've already seen your example, well it's quiet like your answer. for now i will use it. Thanks

Comment: How to write "public TipViewModel Vm => (TipViewModel) ViewModel;" in xaml?